# SSRS return blank value and regular value to function

Tags: sql, visual-studio, reportingservices-2005, reporting-services

In SSRS I have a parameter that is populated from a multi-value list which allows a blank value.

When I select just the blank value it returns unit 123

When I select just "New" it returns unit 987

When I select both owner "New" and the blank value it only returns 987.

Any ideas? Does SSRS not allow you to pass the blank value and a normal value?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have both Labels and Values specified in the Available values for the parameter? Can you include the query you are using for the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about what you are asking. SSRS uses arrays to manage multi value parameters. I would have to see the query to completely understand it but

- You can have an empty array
- You can have an array with one item
- But you cannot have an empty array with one item.

Comment: I think anicolais has a blank value on his list of selection values - so the user is selecting the value that is blank and/or the value that is "New"; ie. the array would have two values - one blank, one "New".